# How do I make a collection fast searchable?

Tags: c#

**EDIT**: I rephrased the question, and it was solved on this post: [How do I search within a collection of type ConfigurationSection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9252878/c-how-do-i-search-within-a-collection-of-type-configurationsection)

**Original Question:**

I am storing a list of config options in my web config. I may have 50 or 100 items in here eventually.

I am using the method described here:

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/asp-net/how-to-add-custom-configuration-settings-for-your-asp-net-application/

The good news:

It works, and I have a _Config collection that has all the

The problem: How do I query _Config for a specific feed? (I will have 50-100, maybe more over time.... someday this will move to a db, but not now, as it is hosted on azure, and I need to avoid azure persistence for now.)

(And since this will execute a lot, perhaps it should be  hashtable or dictionary? but I don't know how to create em...)

I have struggled, and have **been unable to cast _Config into a list or something that I can query.**

**The question is: How do I get _Config (from the link above) into something that I can query for a specific feed?**

The ultimate goal is to have a func that is called to work with a specific feed, and so it needs the config info just from that feed record. In pseudocode, the goal is something like:

```
getFeed(feedname)
    if (_Config.name == feedname) // e.g. feedname is one of the "name" elements in the web.config
        // do the stuff
        GetData(_Config.feedname.url)
    else
        // requested feed is not in our config
        // tell use can't do it
```

Or, (also pseudo code)

```
getFeed(feedname)
    try
        thisPassFeed = _Config.feedname;
        string url = thisPassFeed.url;
        // do the stuff
        GetData(url);
    catch
        // requested feed is not in our config
        // tell use can't do it
        return("can't find that feedname in web.config")
```

Comment: 50 to 100 items is not that many. Don't sweat it.

Comment: 100 feeds in the grand scheme of things is nothing. If you need to look them up using some key (like the feed name), a Dictionary is the data structure to use.

Comment: Also, don't use pseudocode in questions. Pseudocode is something Algorithms 101 lecturers use, not people who actually program.

Comment: What is the type of `_Config`?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a static class that has a private Dictionary member.  In the static constructor access the _Config and do

```
public static class Feeds
{
    private static readonly Dictionary<string, FeedElement> feeds;

    static Feeds()
    {
        feeds = new Dictionary<string, FeedElement>();
        var config = ConfigurationManager.GetSection("feedRetriever") as FeedRetrieverSection;
        foreach (FeedElement feed in config.Feeds)
        {
            feeds.Add(feed.Name, feed);
        }
    }

    static public FeedElement GetFeed(string name)
    {
        return feeds[name];
    }
}
```

Comment: Jared: Would love to! but unfortunately that is not enough info for me to implement on (I am a hobbyist and new to c#)

Comment: @Jonesome I have expanded the sample, you will need to add in your own logic for what happens if the feed is not found by that name (currently it will just return null).

Comment: thanks! To get it to compile, remove the "public" on this: static Feeds()

Comment: seems that the function GetFeed() never invokes the dictionary construction code....

Comment: -1 because in my testing, static Feeds() is never called, so the needed functionality is not avail from this code sample. Sorry!

Comment: @Jonesome It works for me, your testing must be wrong somehow. Note that the static constructor might not be called in a deterministic fashion. The documentation only says it's before it would be needed.

Comment: @Inerdial: I walked it in debugger, and both did not see it called, and did not get appro result. Could be me...