# How do I search within a collection of type ConfigurationSection?

Tags: c#

If I have a collection that is of type ConfigurationSection, **how do I search within the collection?**

(I am a C# noob and hobbyist)

I have this class:

(from http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/asp-net/how-to-add-custom-configuration-settings-for-your-asp-net-application/)

```
public class FeedRetrieverSection : ConfigurationSection  
{  
  [ConfigurationProperty("feeds", IsDefaultCollection =   
  public FeedElementCollection Feeds
    {  
      get { return (FeedElementCollection)this["feeds"]; }  
      set { this["feeds"] = value; }  
    }  
}
```

I see how to iterate through it using a "for each" based on this declaration of _Config:

```
public static FeedRetrieverSection _Config =  
        ConfigurationManager.GetSection("feedRetriever") as FeedRetrieverSection;
```

**What I cannot figure out: How do I search for a given name within the collection?**

Using the declaration of _Config, as shown above, I would want to use linq or a dictionary to just get a single "record" from this list of `<feeds>` ?

Full stack:

Web config has this in it:

```
<feedRetriever>  
    <feeds>  
        <add name="Nettuts+" url="http://feeds.feedburner.com/nettuts" cache="false"/>  
        <add name="Jeremy McPeak" url="http://www.wdonline.com/feeds/blog/rss/" />  
        <add name="Nicholas C. Zakas" url="http://feeds.nczonline.net/blog/" />  
    </feeds>  
</feedRetriever>
```

Which is represented in code this way:

```
public class FeedElement : ConfigurationElement  
{  
    [ConfigurationProperty("name", IsKey = true, IsRequired = true)]  
    public string Name  
    {  
        get { return (string)this["name"]; }  
        set { this["name"] = value; }  
    }  

    // etc for all of the elements...
}
```

Which is wrapped in a ConfigurationElementCollection like so:

```
[ConfigurationCollection(typeof(FeedElement))]  
public class FeedElementCollection : ConfigurationElementCollection  
{  
    protected override ConfigurationElement CreateNewElement()  
    {  
        return new FeedElement();  
    }  

    protected override object GetElementKey(ConfigurationElement element)  
    {  
        return ((FeedElement)element).Name;  
    }  
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I make a collection fast searchable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9251544/how-do-i-make-a-collection-fast-searchable)

Comment: If you have more details to a question, you should edit the old one, not post a new one.

Comment: Edit your original question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9251544/how-do-i-make-a-collection-fast-searchable don't duplicate.

Comment: @Jared: Here is my predicament. My original question was so poorly constructed, that the comments showed it was going in the wrong direction. The edit would be a complete rewrite. I considered deleting the question (can I?), but thought that was not appro. Sorry for the etiquette issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`FeedElementCollection` is a non generic collection which will contains `FeedElement`s. To use LINQ on it you need to make it "generic" with the [OfType<>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913.aspx) or `Cast<>` methods. Then you can do the filtering:

```
_Config.Feeds.OfType<FeedElement>().Where(e => e.Name == "Jeremy McPeak");
```